# Execute command and use the -e flag with the docker run command?

Tags: linux, docker

With docker, I'm able to execute a command when I use the docker run command. In my case, I've to execute a bash script when I use the `docker run` command :

```
docker run --rm --name XXXXX my_image /xxx/xxx/xxx/my_script.sh -s
```

I use the `-s` flag to use an option in my script.

Now, I want to use the `-e` flag available with the `docker run` command. Currently, I use this style of command :

```
docker run -e XXXX-e XXXX --rm --name my_image /XXX/XXX/XXX/XXX -s
```

I want to use this command but with an other "layout", like that :

```
docker run --rm --name XXXXX my_image /xxx/xxx/xxx/my_script.sh -s \
           -e XXXX \
           -e XXXX
```

But if I use this " layout ", I can't use my `-s` flag with my script...

Someone to show me how to do that if it's possible ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 2):

You can't invert the arguments - all arguments to docker itself must be specified before the image name. This is done so that the CMD can be overridden without any ambiguity, like you did by passing `/XXXX -s`.

If you're using a shell script, what you can do instead is this:

```
args=(-e XXXX -e XXXX --rm --name XXXXXX)
docker run "${args[@]}" my_image /XXX/XXX/XXX/XXX -s
```

This way, it is clear which arguments are passed to Docker and which are your command, and you can split your lines without making it confusing.